# change smtp banner on mail enable

Tags: exchange, smtp, email

I want to set an SMTP banner for MailEnable. I followed the [instructions here](http://www.theemailadmin.com/2010/08/how-to-change-your-smtp-banner-for-fun-and-profit) and nothing happens.

When I telnet to my server on port 25 I am getting the following:

```
220 MyComputerNameHere Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 7.5.7601.17514 ready at Thu, 3 Nov 2011 16:45:34 -0400
```

ESMTP? Is that exchange? How is that possible?

The source of the problem is that I am getting:

> Warning - Reverse DNS does not match SMTP Banner

when checking my email server.

I have been stuck on this for more than one day, any help will be really, really appreciated.

### Update

- OS: Windows Server 2008 R2
- Mail: Mail Enable.

I am connecting from the same the server to check the warning I am talking about check [here](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=smtp:70.38.38.103)

Comment: It would be more constructive to provide the information *before* waiting for comments.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like the server you're connecting to is running the SMTP service in IIS 7.5. There's no build (version) number 7.5 for Exchange Server.

Here are the build numbers for Exchange server:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/158530

And here are the version numbers for IIS:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224609

The system requirements for MailEnable don't list IIS except for webmail and administration. It doesn't list the SMTP component of IIS as a requirement. Does the server you have MailEnable installed on also have IIS SMTP installed?

Comment: I have a Spam mail header of k-dev's system. So you can see that he uses MailEnable which then forwards to the Internet: http://zy0.de/q/70.38.38.103. I also checked while writing my answer below and then it definitively was an IIS or Exchange. So k-dev changed it.

Answer (score 0):

This looks as being Microsoft Exchange. But as you already cited, there are possibilities to forge the greeting line. So this doesn't prove anything.

How is this possible? You connect to Exchange! Or something that pretends to be Exchange. Who knows when you don't provide any further information. "My server" doesn't even say which Operating System, mail software, hostname and IP you have.

Comment: Hi, I added more information, do you need to know something else?

Comment: @k-dev Shutdown you server **now**. You have a massive Spam problem. Ask for professional help, otherwise you are running in delivery problems very soon. See http://www.mcafee.com/threat-intelligence/ip/default.aspx?ip=70.38.38.103

Answer (score 0):

The message indicates a problem in your DNS configuration of the host.  But with the information you have provided it is difficult to tell if this is for the Mail server, or the client connecting to.